# La página no está redirigiendo adecuadamente - Rutas en laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Estoy trabajando en laravael 5.7. Cada que cargo el proyecto me genera el error: La página no está redirigiendo adecuadamente. Lo que realice fue modificar la rutas de autenticacion de login por defecto que trae laravel.

**Este es el error:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

rutas en el archivo `web.php`

```
//logeo
Route::get('/', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
Route::post('/login', 'Auth\LoginController@login')->name('ingreso');
Route::post('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');

//registro
Route::get('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm')->name('register');
Route::post('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@register');

//olvido de contraseña (reseteo)
Route::get('password/reset', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm')->name('password.request');
Route::post('password/email', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail')->name('password.email');
Route::get('password/reset/{token}', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm')->name('password.reset');
Route::post('password/reset', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset')->name('password.update');

//verifiacion de correo
Route::get('email/verify', 'Auth\VerificationController@show')->name('verification.notice');
Route::get('email/verify/{id}', 'Auth\VerificationController@verify')->name('verification.verify');
Route::get('email/resend', 'Auth\VerificationController@resend')->name('verification.resend');


//Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);

Route::resource('cuentas/cliente', 'ClienteController')->middleware('verified');

Route::resource('cuentas/cuenta', 'CuentaController');

Route::resource('cuentas/abono', 'AbonoController');

Route::post('cuentas/abono', 'AbonoController@abonar');

Route::resource('seguridad/usuario', 'UserController');


//actualizar contraseña
Route::get('user/pass', 'UserController@formUpdatePass');
Route::post('user/updatepass', 'UserController@updatepass')->name('updatepass');

Route::get('logout', '\App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');

//si la ruta ingresada no es ninguna de las anteriores lo dirige haacia el login
Route::get('{any?}', function ($any) {
    return redirect('/');
})->where('any', '.*');
```

archivo `LoginController.php`

```
 namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;
    
    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
    use Session;
    
    
    class LoginController extends Controller
    {
        /*
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        | Login Controller
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        |
        | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
        | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
        | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
        |
        */
    
        use AuthenticatesUsers;
    
        /**
         * Where to redirect users after login.
         *
         * @var string
         */
        protected $redirectTo = '/cuentas/cliente';
    
        /**
         * Create a new controller instance.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
        }
    
         public function logout(Request $request) {
             Auth::logout();
            Session::flush();
            return redirect('/');
          }
    }
```

archivo `login.blade.php`

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">{{ __('Login') }}</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('ingreso') }}">
                        @csrf

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('E-Mail Address') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autofocus>

                                @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Password') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="password" required>

                                @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                <div class="form-check">
                                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember" {{ old('remember') ? 'checked' : '' }}>

                                    <label class="form-check-label" for="remember">
                                        {{ __('Remember Me') }}
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                            <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    {{ __('Login') }}
                                </button>

                                @if (Route::has('password.request'))
                                    <a class="btn btn-link" href="{{ route('password.request') }}">
                                        {{ __('Forgot Your Password?') }}
                                    </a>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

archivo `kernel.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    /**
     * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
     *
     * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middleware = [
        \App\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware groups.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
            'bindings',
        ],
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware.
     *
     * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
    ];

    /**
     * The priority-sorted list of middleware.
     *
     * This forces non-global middleware to always be in the given order.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middlewarePriority = [
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
    ];
}
```

Comment: Que error te marca?

Comment: Deberias ponerle la / al principio a todas tus rutas, como hiciste en las dos primeras con "/login" y "/"

Comment: @FrancoDreher ya lo hice, y sigue igual

Comment: @EdgarGc es este: La página no está redirigiendo adecuadamente - Rutas en laravel. igual adjunte la imagen del error.

Comment: prueba quitando esta ruta `Route::get('{any?}', function ($any) {
    return redirect('/');
})->where('any', '.*');`

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ listo, me sale error 404

Comment: prueba quitándole el middleware `->middleware('verified')` a la ruta a la que rediriges.

Comment: Qué utilizas, `xampp`, `php artisan serve`, `laragon`?

Comment: @L.Flor laragon, phpmyadmin y php artisan serve

Comment: Muéstranos tu `$routeMiddleware` dentro de tu archivo `Kernel.php`

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ Ya la quite y sigue igual

Comment: @L.Flor ya agrege el archivo a la pregunta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al parecer es un error por el navegador. Hice pruebas en chrome y firefox y me funciona perfectamente. Estaba usando Microsoft Edge y en este me slieron los errores dichos en la pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Si usas Xampp, debes modificar la carpeta de hosts para que te muestre la página web, si eso no funciona intenta correr `php artisan serve` mediante git o la consola de comandos de Windows a ver si te deja